# Android code for checking visibility of edit text

Tags: android

Hi i have a small problem. I have spinner when i select "yes" edit text 1 and edit text 2 will display when i select "NO" edit text will disappear its working fine for me. But when i press on button for validating the edit text logcat as "AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client". this is the code.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(edittext1.getText().toString().length()==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Key NO(FX)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(sfpchangeddata.contains("SFP Changed"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select SFP changed or Not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(edittext2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    if(edittext2.getText().toString().length()!=0)
                    {

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Siga SFP serial No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
                else if(edittext3.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    if(edittext3.getText().toString().length()!=0)
                    {

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Old Siga SFP serial No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the visibility for an editText by using [isShown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown%28%29) on your ediText

Answer (score 2):

**isShown()** method returns boolean value, so you can use this in your if loop.

```
if(edittext.isShown())
{
      //Set the code here if the edittext is visible.
}
else
{
      //Here the code which will run if ediitext is invisible.
}
```

Hope this will help you.